# Create hierarchical XML from SQL Server tables

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, t-sql, webforms

I have a SQL Server database with 3 tables and I need to create an XML file with hierarchical structure from these tables.

One table contains products:

```
ProductID   ProductLanguageID ProductDefaultShopID  ProductNumber ProductName ProductPrice
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
100101@@Inc LANG2             Inc                   100101        ABC         159,61
100102@@Inc LANG2             Inc                   100102        BCD         159,61
100105@@Inc LANG2             Inc                   100105        FRE         159,61
100106@@Inc LANG2             Inc                   100106        GDE         159,61
```

the second has groups

```
GroupID     GroupLanguageID   GroupName          GroupNumber
------------------------------------------------------------
1@@Inc      LANG2             AAA                1
1.01@@Inc   LANG2             BBB                1.01
1.02@@Inc   LANG2             CCC                1.02
1.03@@Inc   LANG2             DDD                1.03
1.12@@Inc   LANG2             GGG                1.12
```

the third languages

```
LanguageID  LanguageCode2   LanguageName
----------------------------------------
LANG1       ES              Spain
LANG2       EN              English
```

I have also 2 tables that don´t have any connections to another tables:

Group Relations Table

```
GroupRelationsGroupID   GroupRelationsParentID
--------------------------------------------
1.01@@Inc               1@@Inc
1.02@@Inc               1@@Inc
1.03@@Inc               1.02@@Inc
1.12@@Inc               1.03@@Inc
```

Group Product Relation Table

```
GroupProductRelationGroupID    GroupProductRelationProductID
-------------------------------------------------------------
1.01@@Inc                      100101@@Inc
1.03@@Inc                      100102@@Inc
1.12@@Inc                      100105@@Inc
```

The XML output should have following structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <productgroup1>
    <groupname>AAA</groupname>
    <productgroup2>
      <groupname>BBB</groupname>
      <productgroup3>
        <groupname>CCC</groupname>
        <products>
          <product>
            <itemName>ABC</itemName>
            <itemNumber>100303</itemNumber>
            <itemPrice>159.61</itemPrice>
            <ExtraProductgroup>
              <extraProductgroupName>GGG</extraProductgroupName>
              <itemName>FRE</itemName>
              <itemNumber>100305</itemNumber>
              <itemPrice>159.61</itemPrice>
          </ExtraProductgroup>
          </product>
        <product>
            <itemName>BCD</itemName>
            <itemNumber>100302</itemNumber>
            <itemPrice>159.61</itemPrice>
          </product>
        </products>
      </productgroup3>
    </productgroup2>
  </productgroup1>
</root>
```

I may only use T-SQL and C# (ASP.Net Web Forms).  HELP!!! :-)

Comment: I see no way to get that XML from that data. For instance, where does itemColor come from? What about ExtraProductgroup? If you want anyone to have a chance, at least create the desired output from the given input by hand. Otherwise, we're just guessing here.

Comment: You have a ProductNumber and a ProductID being the number with `@@Inc` - What is the *real* ID? Seems odd... Neither of them is to be found somewhere in the other data. How is a Product bound to a group? The groups seem to be hierarchically nested. Is there a maximum depth? Group and Group relation hold IDs not to be found in the Group table... You must provide **working sample data with an example output fitting to this data!!** Please prepare a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Code or [fiddle](www.sqlfiddle.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must admit, that I really doubt, that you will get happy with this structur... Why are products below groupLevel3 when they are related to a level2 group? Why is ABC and BCD situated on the same level? How is the ExtraGroup found?

This solution will not solve all data generically, but - at least - brings back exactly the wanted result with the given data.

```
CREATE TABLE #Products(ProductID VARCHAR(50),ProductLanguageID VARCHAR(50),ProductNumber INT, ProductName VARCHAR(50), ProductPrice DECIMAL(14,4));
INSERT INTO #Products VALUES
 ('100101@@Inc','LANG2',100101,'ABC',159.61)
,('100102@@Inc','LANG2',100102,'BCD',159.61)
,('100105@@Inc','LANG2',100105,'FRE',159.61)
,('100106@@Inc','LANG2',100106,'GDE',159.61)
;

CREATE TABLE #Groups(GroupID VARCHAR(50),GroupLanguageID VARCHAR(50),GroupName VARCHAR(50),GroupNumber DECIMAL(5,2));
INSERT INTO #Groups VALUES
 ('1@@Inc','LANG2','AAA',1)
,('1.01@@Inc','LANG2','BBB',1.01)
,('1.02@@Inc','LANG2','CCC',1.02)
,('1.03@@Inc','LANG2','DDD',1.03)
,('1.12@@Inc','LANG2','GGG',1.12)
;

CREATE TABLE #Languages(LanguageID VARCHAR(50),LanguageCode2 VARCHAR(50),LanguageName VARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO #Languages VALUES
 ('LANG1','ES','Spain')
,('LANG2','EN','English');

CREATE TABLE #GroupRelations(GroupRelationsGroupID VARCHAR(50),GroupRelationsParentID VARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO #GroupRelations VALUES
 ('1.01@@Inc','1@@Inc')
,('1.02@@Inc','1.01@@Inc')
,('1.03@@Inc','1.02@@Inc')
,('1.12@@Inc','1.03@@Inc');

CREATE TABLE #GroupProductRelations(GroupProductRelationGroupID VARCHAR(50),GroupProductRelationProductID VARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO #GroupProductRelations VALUES
 ('1.01@@Inc','100101@@Inc')
,('1.03@@Inc','100102@@Inc')
,('1.12@@Inc','100105@@Inc');


GO

WITH TopGroups AS
(
    SELECT gr.GroupID
    FROM #Groups AS gr
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM #GroupRelations AS x WHERE gr.GroupID = x.GroupRelationsGroupID)
)
,recGroup AS
(
    SELECT 1 AS GroupLevel
          ,g.GroupID
          ,g.GroupLanguageID
          ,g.GroupName
          ,g.GroupNumber
          ,gr.GroupRelationsParentID AS ParentGroupID
    FROM #Groups AS g
    LEFT JOIN #GroupRelations AS gr ON g.GroupID=gr.GroupRelationsGroupID 
    WHERE gr.GroupRelationsParentID IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT prev.GroupLevel + 1
          ,gNext.GroupID
          ,gNext.GroupLanguageID
          ,gNext.GroupName
          ,gNext.GroupNumber
          ,grNext.GroupRelationsParentID
    FROM #GroupRelations AS grNext
        INNER JOIN #Groups AS gNext ON grNext.GroupRelationsGroupID=gNext.GroupID
        INNER JOIN recGroup AS prev ON grNext.GroupRelationsParentID=prev.GroupID
)
SELECT *
INTO #tmpFullResult
FROM recGroup
LEFT JOIN #GroupProductRelations AS gp ON recGroup.GroupID=gp.GroupProductRelationGroupID
LEFT JOIN #Products AS p ON gp.GroupProductRelationProductID=p.ProductID
LEFT JOIN #Languages AS l ON p.ProductLanguageID=l.LanguageID;

SELECT * FROM #tmpFullResult;

SELECT lvl1.GroupName AS groupName 
      ,(     
        SELECT lvl2.GroupName AS groupName
              ,(
                SELECT lvl3.GroupName AS groupName
                    ,(
                        SELECT prod.ProductName AS itemName
                              ,prod.ProductNumber AS itemNumber
                              ,prod.ProductPrice AS itemPrice
                              ,(
                                    SELECT prodExtra.GroupName AS extraProductGroupName
                                          ,prodExtra.ProductName AS itemName
                                          ,prodExtra.ProductNumber AS itemNumber
                                          ,prodExtra.ProductPrice AS itemPrice
                                    FROM #tmpFullResult AS prodExtra
                                    WHERE prodExtra.ProductID IS NOT NULL 
                                      AND prodExtra.GroupLevel=5
                                    FOR XML PATH('ExtraProductgroup'),TYPE
                               )
                        FROM #tmpFullResult AS prod
                        WHERE prod.ProductID IS NOT NULL 
                          AND prod.GroupLevel<5
                        FOR XML PATH('product'),ROOT('products'),TYPE
                     )
                FROM #tmpFullResult AS lvl3
                WHERE lvl3.GroupLevel=3 AND lvl3.ParentGroupID=lvl2.GroupID
                FOR XML PATH('productGroup3'),TYPE
               )
        FROM #tmpFullResult AS lvl2
        WHERE lvl2.GroupLevel=2 AND lvl2.ParentGroupID=lvl1.GroupID
        FOR XML PATH('productGroup2'),TYPE
       )
FROM #tmpFullResult AS lvl1
WHERE lvl1.ParentGroupID IS NULL
FOR XML PATH('productgroup1'),ROOT('root')
GO
DROP TABLE #tmpFullResult;
DROP TABLE #GroupProductRelations
DROP TABLE #Groups
DROP TABLE #GroupRelations
DROP TABLE #Languages
DROP TABLE #Products
```

The result

```
<root>
  <productgroup1>
    <groupName>AAA</groupName>
    <productGroup2>
      <groupName>BBB</groupName>
      <productGroup3>
        <groupName>CCC</groupName>
        <products>
          <product>
            <itemName>ABC</itemName>
            <itemNumber>100101</itemNumber>
            <itemPrice>159.6100</itemPrice>
            <ExtraProductgroup>
              <extraProductGroupName>GGG</extraProductGroupName>
              <itemName>FRE</itemName>
              <itemNumber>100105</itemNumber>
              <itemPrice>159.6100</itemPrice>
            </ExtraProductgroup>
          </product>
          <product>
            <itemName>BCD</itemName>
            <itemNumber>100102</itemNumber>
            <itemPrice>159.6100</itemPrice>
            <ExtraProductgroup>
              <extraProductGroupName>GGG</extraProductGroupName>
              <itemName>FRE</itemName>
              <itemNumber>100105</itemNumber>
              <itemPrice>159.6100</itemPrice>
            </ExtraProductgroup>
          </product>
        </products>
      </productGroup3>
    </productGroup2>
  </productgroup1>
</root>
```

Comment: @AntonTredder Well, sometime we have to take things as they are ... What I do not understand at the moment: Is this question solved (given data => expected output) or not? If not: Why not?

Comment: @AntonTredder please add some more rows to your sample data in your question to reflect this (use the edit option) and fiddle them into your expected output too. I do not really understand, what you want/need...

Comment: @AntonTredder, You just placed exactly the same question again. This is a good decision as it pulls much more attraction to this complex question. I'd suggest the following: Do a rollback to your last changes here and close this question. As I invested quite some time and actually solved the given question with the given data I'd kindly ask you to vote me up and (extra action) tick the acceptance check to close this question. I'll pop up at your new question (tomorrow) and help you there - if I can... Thx